# monacaで直接gcmのregistrationidを取得するには？

Tags: javascript, gcm

Monacaを利用してプッシュ通知を行う場合、MobileBackendを使うような進め方で、ググってもほかに方法がないようですが、要は、Monaca、つまりJavascriptではGCMのRegistrationIdを取得することはできないということでしょうか？もしできるのであれば、教えてください。